# Datepicker Textbox Focus event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, focus

I have an issue with `focus` event of textbox which gets called multiple times. Datepicker is bound to that textbox using jquery.ui.

Error in chrome:

> uncaught rangeerror maximum call stack size exceeded .

In chrome and Safari browser

JS:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$('#datepicker').focus(function () {

   alert(1);
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>Date:
    <input id="datepicker" type="text">

</p>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/je6t1xqh/

Comment: So you get the described error with your fiddle? What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: I have found another solution. I have added new class on text box and on click event of text box I performed my business logic